# Write in file after specific sentence

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I want to add some data into text file after find specific sentence, as an example i want to add some strings after find `This the place to write your sentence`
How can i make that, I write correctly to text file using `StreamWriter` .

Can anyone give me a bit of code or link ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a gimme-teh-codez site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not easy to insert text in a file, as you would have to move the data after the insert point to make room for the new text. A `StreamWriter` does not support the file operations needed for that.

The simple approach is to read the file into a string, change the string and then write it to the file:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
string insertPoint = "This the place to write your sentence";
int index = text.IndexOf(insertPoint) + insertPoint.Length;
text = text.Insert(index, "Text to insert");
File.WriteAllText(fileNAme, text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) to read the entire text file into a string. Then to find the specific sentence "This the place to write your sentence" use the method [String.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx). Once you have the index you can use the method [String.Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx) to add whatever text you want. Finally overwrite the existing file with the new string you just created using [File.WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines(v=vs.110).aspx). You can also use StreamWriter.WriteLine method if you wish to.

Answer (score 0):

It's really all about `System.IO.Stream` (which implements `IDisposable`, so you should use it in a `using` statement), `byte[]`(aka buffers), and `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII` or the more commonly used `System.Text.UTF8encoding.UTF8` encoding.

---

With that said, there are static methods on `System.IO.File` that make this operation quite easy.

```
        System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8; // we don't have to declare and set a variable, I'm just doing this to emphasize the encoding class and it's usage.

        string myText = "My Text To Assert";
        string lookupText = "This the place to write your sentence";

        string filePath = "C:\test.txt";

        string payload = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath, encoding);
        payload.Replace(lookupText, String.Format("{0}{1}", lookupText, myText));
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, payload);
```

Comment: `insert` is likely better then `replace`, but I'll offer this up as a possble solution that differs from Guffa's